# custom hooks for data fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, antd

i've made this custom hook to fetch data using a **fetcher** and return a state with data to show in an antd table ( love them ).
I'm not sure this is the correct way to use hooks, i've added comments inside my code where i've questions about.

```
import { useEffect, useReducer } from 'react';
import { useLocation, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import queryString from 'query-string'

const initialState = { data: [], loading: true };

const fetchData = (fetcher, params, dispatch) => {

    //in this case i need to change my state to loading, the reducer will do the trick, but i fill this kinda triky, should i call the fatcher after the dispatch end using an effect?

    dispatch({ type: 'FETCHING' })
    fetcher({ ...params, page: params.page > 0 ? params.page - 1 : params.page }, response => dispatch({ type: 'DATA_RECEIVED', payload: response.data }));
    return () => {
        console.log('unmounting useGridDataFetch')
    };
}

const handlePageChange = (page, history, location) => {
    const qparams = queryString.parse(location.search)
    const qs = Object.keys(qparams).map(key => key != 'page' ? `&${key}=${qparams[key]}` : '')
    history.push(`${history.location.pathname}?page=${page}${qs.reduce((acc,val)=> acc + val , '')}`)
}


const useGridDataFetch = (fetcher, initialParams) => {
    const location = useLocation()
    const history = useHistory()
    const params = { ...initialParams, ...queryString.parse(location.search) }

    // to use history and location inside my reducer to change the querystring on page change, i had to put the reducer definition inside the body of the hook, is there a better way?

    const reducer = (state, action) => {
        switch (action.type) {
            case 'FETCHING':
                return { loading: true };
            case 'DATA_RECEIVED':
                const pagination = {
                    pageSize: action.payload.pageable.pageSize,
                    current: action.payload.pageable.pageNumber + 1,
                    total: action.payload.totalElements,
                    onChange: page => handlePageChange(page, history, location)
                }
                return { dataSource: action.payload.content, loading: false, pagination };
            default:
                throw new Error();
        }
    }

    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
    useEffect(() => fetchData(fetcher, params, dispatch), [location.search])

    return [state, (_params) => fetchData(fetcher, { ...params, ..._params }, dispatch)]
}


export default useGridDataFetch
```

In general every tips you can give me to improve my code will be appreciate.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to help you

First of all you have to extract reducer from the hook.
`reducer` function should be independent from the hook,
because `useReducer(reducer, initialState);` uses these 2 parameters `reducer` and `initialState` only once, and doesn't update it on each next call. As a result you can't use `handlePageChange` method inside the reducer.

Second point is your reducer has to return data with the same interface like `{ data: Array, isLoading: Boolean }`. In your case, you have 3 different response from reducer: after init - `{ data: Array, loading: Boolean }`, after `FETCHING` -  `{ loading: Boolean }`, and after `DATA_RECEIVED` - `{ dataSource: Object, loading: Boolean, pagination: Object }`

I recommend you don't use useReducer. I'm going to suggest my implementation of your code

```js
const useGridDataFetch = (fetcher, initialParams) => {
  const { data, isLoading } = useGetData(fetcher, initialParams);
  const { dataSource, pagination } = useGetPreparedData(data);
  
  return {
    isLoading,
    dataSource,
    pagination,
  }
}

const useGetData = (fetcher, initialParams) => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [data, setData] = useState({});

  const location = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    const params = {
      ...initialParams,
      ...queryString.parse(location.search)
    }
    setIsLoading(true);
    fetcher({
      ...params,
      page: params.page > 0 ? params.page - 1 : params.page
    }, response => {
      setData(response.data);
      setIsLoading(false);
    });
  }, [location.search]);

  return {
    isLoading,
    data
  }
}

const useGetPreparedData = (data) => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const history = useHistory();

  const handlePageChange = useCallback((page) => {
    const qparams = queryString.parse(location.search);
    const qs = Object.keys(qparams).map(key => key != 'page' ? `&${key}=${qparams[key]}` : '')
    history.push(`${location.pathname}?page=${page}${qs.reduce((acc,val)=> acc + val , '')}`)
  }, [location.pathname, location.search, history]);

  return useMemo(() => {
    if (!data.content) {
      return {
        dataSource: [],
        pagination: {}
      }
    }

    const pagination = {
      pageSize: data.pageable.pageSize,
      current: data.pageable.pageNumber + 1,
      total: data.totalElements,
      onChange: page => handlePageChange(page)
    }

    return {
      dataSource: data.content,
      pagination
    };
  }, [data, handlePageChange])
}
```

I may have some errors with this code, but i think the main idea is simple

Comment: well, first of all thank you for the response. I've fixed a couple of things in your code but is working nice, just a couple of things: why should i avoid useReducer? is better to use multiple useState instead? as you can see in the code,  now there is a sequence of state setter so i have to set the loading state first => fetch data => set data => set loading. This will cause an additional render cause the setIsLoading(false). Thank you.

Comment: @claud.io Thank you, I've approved your fixes. I recommended you to avoid useReducer in this case because it creates more places for some mistakes like I've described at the beginning of the answer. I recommend writing code more simple and don't give even a chance to make a mistake when someone after you will update your code.

Comment: The count of re-renders will be the same because when you call the first dispatch  it's first re-render and the second dispatch it's the second re-render. In the case with useState, first re-render calls on setLoading(true) and after fetching data both methods setLoading and setData merging to single re-render.